# JavaFX Concurrency - Using a task, which runs in a thread, but hangs the UI

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency, javafx-8

### There are a lot of questions and answer around concurrency, and mine could be similar to others, but for me it's not a duplicate as for some reason I must be missing something and hope to get some advice...

My question is more one where I need a second pair of eyes to point out what I'm doing incorrectly to enable my code to run in a background thread, but also updated the GUI, without freezing it.

Initially, a PDF file is uploaded to the application, using a task in a thread.

This works fine.

A progress bar is displayed, which animates without issue:

### uploadFile()

```
public void uploadFile(File fileToProcess) {

  fileBeingProcessed = fileToProcess;

  Task<Parent> uploadingFileTask = new Task<Parent>() {
    @Override
    public Parent call() {
      try {
        progressBarStackPane.setVisible(true);
        pdfPath = loadPDF(fileBeingProcessed.getAbsolutePath());
        createPDFViewer();
        openDocument();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainSceneController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      return null;
    }
  };

  uploadingFileTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
      fileHasBeenUploaded = true;
      progressBarStackPane.setVisible(false);
      uploadFilePane.setVisible(false);
      tabPane.setVisible(true);

      /* This is where I am getting issue, more so in createThumbnailPanels() */

      setupThumbnailFlowPane();
      createThumbnailPanels();

      /****** ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ******/

    }
  });

  uploadingFileTask.setOnFailed(evt -> {
    uploadingFileTask.getException().printStackTrace(System.err);
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(uploadingFileTask.getException().getSuppressed()));
  });

  Thread uploadingFileThread = new Thread(uploadingFileTask);
  uploadingFileThread.start();

}
```

Once the document has been uploaded, it is displayed in a tab which allows the user to view the document.

There is a secondary tab, which, after upload, is disabled, until the completion of another task called `createThumbnailPanelsTask`;

However, before this task is ran, the `FlowPane` for the Thumbnail Panels is created.  This seems to work without issue, and doesn't appear to be the cause of the GUI hanging (this is clearly a loop in `createThumbnailPanelsTask`, but for clarity I will show `setupThumbnailFlowPane()`):

### setupThumbnailFlowPane()

```
public void setupThumbnailFlowPane() {
  stage = model.getStage();
  root = model.getRoot();

  secondaryTabScrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
  secondaryTabScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

  /**
  This will be removed from here when refactored but for now it is here,
  I don't think this is anything to do with my issue
  **/

  Set<Node> nodes = secondaryTabScrollPane.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
  for (final Node node : nodes) {
    if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
      ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar) node;
      if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        sb.setUnitIncrement(30.0);
      }
      if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
        sb.setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  }

  secondaryTab = new FlowPane();
  secondaryTab.setId("secondaryTab");
  secondaryTab.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTSLATEGRAY, new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
  secondaryTab.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
  secondaryTab.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
  secondaryTab.setPrefWrapLength(stage.widthProperty().intValue() - 150);
  secondaryTab.setHgap(5);
  secondaryTab.setVgap(30);
  secondaryTab.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT, BorderStrokeStyle.NONE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(8, 10, 20, 10))));
  secondaryTab.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
}
```

Finally, `createThumbnailPanels()` is called, which is where I believe I am getting the problem.

What is suppose to happen is, after the document has uploaded, the upload file pane is hidden, revealing the Viewer Tab, and also the Secondary Tab.

The secondary tab is disabled at this point, and also has a loading image (a `gif`) on the left side of it.

The intended behaviour, is that the `createThumbnailPanels()` task will run in the background, and until it is complete, the tab will remain disabled, however, during this time, the `gif` image will be rotating, giving the impression there is some loading occurring.

Once the loading has completed, the `gif` is removed, and the tab is enabled, allowing the user to navigate to it, and see the generated thumbnail panels.

This all works, however, as mentioned, the task is hanging the GUI:

### createThumbnailPanels()

```
public void createThumbnailPanels() {
  Task<Void> createThumbnailPanelsTask = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
      if (model.getIcePdfDoc() != null) {
        numberOfPagesInDocument = model.getIcePdfDoc().getNumberOfPages();
        for (int thumbIndex = 0; thumbIndex < numberOfPagesInDocument; thumbIndex++) {
          ThumbnailPanel tb = new ThumbnailPanel(thumbIndex, main, model);
          Thumbnail tn = new Thumbnail(tb);
          model.setThumbnailAt(tn, thumbIndex);
          eventHandlers.setMouseEventsForThumbnails(tb);

          /*
          I have added this in as I am under the impression that a task runs in a background thread,
          and then to update the GUI, I need to call this:
          */

          Platform.runLater(() -> {
            secondaryTab.getChildren().add(tb);
          });

        }

      }

      return null;
    }
  };

  createThumbnailPanelsTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {

      /*
      Further GUI modification run in setOnSucceeded so it runs on main GUI thread(?)
      */
      secondaryTabScrollPane.setContent(secondaryTab);
      secondaryTab.setDisable(false);
      secondaryTab.setGraphic(null);

    }
  });

  createThumbnailPanelsTask.setOnFailed(evt -> {
    createThumbnailPanelsTask.getException().printStackTrace(System.err);
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(createThumbnailPanelsTask.getException().getSuppressed()));
  });

  Thread createThumbnailPanelsThread = new Thread(createThumbnailPanelsTask);
  createThumbnailPanelsThread.start();
}
```

Everything, bar the GUI hanging while it creates the panels, works fine.

Once they've been created, the GUI can be controlled again, the loading `gif` has been removed, the tab is enabled and the user can navigate to it and view the panels.

*Clearly*, there is something I am missing about concurrency here.

As mentioned, I was under the impression that a Task runs in a background thread, so I'm a little confused by why it doesn't appear to be doing this.  Again, clearly something I am missing.

### I have read, and read, and read about concurrency, but just can't seem to work out where in my approach I have gone wrong.  I am tempted to try using a Service, however, I feel that I am just over complicating things by considering that, and that there is clearly a simply way to do what I want to achieve.

Any help will be greatly appreciated... a push in the right direction, or some clarification on where I have gone wrong in my understanding.

Thanks in advance, no doubt it's something obvious that once sorted will help me avoid this issue in future!

### UPDATED CODE

### createThumbnailPanels()

```
 public void createThumbnailPanels() {
        Task<Void> createThumbnailPanelsTask = new Task<Void>() {
            //TODO: Need to check that it's a PDF
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                if (model.getIcePdfDoc() != null) {
                    numberOfPagesInDocument = model.getIcePdfDoc().getNumberOfPages();
                    for (int thumbIndex= 0; thumbIndex< numberOfPagesInDocument; thumbIndex++) {
                        ThumbnailPanel tb = new ThumbnailPanel(thumbIndex, main, model);
                        Thumbnail tn = new Thumbnail(tb);                        
                        eventHandlers.setMouseEventsForThumbnails(tb);       
                        model.setThumbnailAt(tn, thumbIndex);
                        model.setThumbnailPanels(tb);
                    }
                    setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPane();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        createThumbnailPanelsTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
//              setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPane();
            }
        });

        createThumbnailPanelsTask.setOnFailed(evt -> {

createThumbnailPanelsTask.getException().printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.err.println(Arrays.toString(createThumbnailPanelsTask.getException().getSuppressed()));
        });

        Thread createThumbnailPanelsThread = new Thread(createThumbnailPanelsTask);
        createThumbnailPanelsThread.start();
    }
```

### setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPane()

```
 public void setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPane() {
         Task<Void> setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneTask = new Task<Void>() {
            //TODO: Need to check that it's a PDF
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                 Platform.runLater(() -> {                     
                    secondaryTab.getChildren().addAll(model.getThumbnailPanels());
                    secondaryTabScrollPane.setContent(main.informationExtractionPanel);
                    secondaryTab.setDisable(false);
                    secondaryTab.setGraphic(null);
                  });   

                return null;
            }
        };


        setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneTask.setOnFailed(evt -> {
                setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneTask.getException().printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.err.println(Arrays.toString(setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneTask.getException().getSuppressed()));
        });

        Thread setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneThread = new Thread(setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneTask);
        setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPaneThread.start();
    }
```

FYI: If I call `setThumbnailPanelsToScrollPane();` in the setOnSucceeded, it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I'm not shouting, I'm using formatting to highlight key parts of what I've wrote, my thoughts so to speak, and the code is complete, it's kept minimal related to the issue I am having, and can be verified as it's a concurrency issue... where in your mind have I failed the MCVE?

Comment: it's missing both the minimal and the verifiable, in fact it is not even an example, just snippets .. always wondering how anybody could think those snippets would be even near a mcve, provided they read the help page. Unnecessary bolding _is_ shouting ... tone down, please. BTW, assuming your first task snippet is running off the fx app thread, it's wrong to call progressBar.setVisible

Comment: Thanks, I'm more concerned about concurrency at the moment hence my question but cheers for the input.

Comment: toggling a property of a control that's added to the scenegraph from a background thread is-a concurrency error ;)

Comment: Toggling the visibility of a stack pane at the start of a Task is a concurrency error?

Comment: Should I be doing it outside the task before I start the task running?

Comment: sure, it's called inside the call method, isn't it? And that runs on the background thread ..

Comment: Ahh I thought it made more sense to start it as the task was running, but I guess as it's updating the GUI that's why that's not the best practice?

Comment: Regarding the visibility of the `ProgressBar`, if you're goal is to only have it be visible while the `Task` is running just bind the `Node.visible` property to the `Worker.running` property. The `Task` class ensures updates to the various `Worker` properties happen on the FX thread.

Comment: "_...but I guess as it's updating the GUI that's why that's not the best practice?_". It's not just "not best practice" but actively harmful. JavaFX is single-threaded (i.e. not thread-safe) and live scene-graphs must _never_ be accessed and/or modified from a background thread. Doing so can lead to all sorts of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks Slaw. Definitely something for me to look into further.  Is there actually any defined way to do large tasks in the background and then update the GUI without it hanging the GUI?  I've worked out a different approach which will keep the UX in feel with what I'm going for, just a shame I can't get it to do heavy lifting in the background and then add all the Thumbnail Panels to the none active tab without it hanging!

Comment: Thank you Kleopatra as well!

Comment: You can create and modify `Node`s on any thread, as stated by the class documentation: "_`Node` objects may be constructed and modified on any thread as long they are **not yet attached to a `Scene` in a `Window` that is showing.** An application must attach nodes to such a `Scene` or modify them on the JavaFX Application Thread._".  Note that attaching a complicated node graph to the scene can still hang the GUI just from processing the sheer number of nodes. If needed, look into only creating what you need at the time or using a virtual control such as `ListView`.

Comment: Cheers for your help guys... I've taken your suggested Slaw, and have looked into virtualisation.  In doing this I came across ControlsFX, and GridViews (https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html), as a ListView didn't seem like it would be ideal for my situation.

Comment: I didn't actually have a hand in writing the initial app, but it is down to me to port it over to JavaFX, so as I am going through I'm attempting to resolve issues based on the current code, so I get a bit 1 track minded trying to utilise the current code, but by seeing ListViews and Virtualisation, it was clear to me that the original approach was the cause of my pain!

Comment: Thank you so much again for the help, and have +1's all round for just generally being StackOverflow legends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getChildren().add` is running on the **JavaFX** GUI thread(thats what `Platform.runLater` does),  but its only required to run it in a `Platform.runLater` if the parent that you add children to is connected to the root of the shown gui, that means you should be able to add children to a parent that is not connected to any root, and add the whole parent to the root at the end of the children addition process, if you're doing `Platform.runLater` in any asynchronous code it will run on the gui thread in your case it is in your asynchronous `for` loop adding `ThumbnailPanels` and if the number of them is large the gui will hang.

Comment: secondaryTab is created like so `secondaryTab = new FlowPane();` and isn't attached to the root til `secondaryTabScrollPane.setContent(secondaryTab);` ... I have removed the Platform.runLater, but without any joy.

Comment: I have also added all the thumbnail panels to a new ArrayList, and then used this array list to addAll() ... `secondaryTab.getChildren().addAll(model.getThumbnailPanels());` but still getting the same issue.

Comment: I am also forced to use Platform.runLater() when running `secondaryTab.getChildren().addAll(model.getThumbnailPanels());` despite this also being in a separate task. I will add updated code.

Comment: Eventually you need to add all of the children to the shown root, and because there are a lot of them it will cause the GUI thread to hang a little, no matter what. But since you've mentioned setOnSucceeded is not called I'd say its a red flag, debug the code and see where exactly the hang occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Slaw got me on the right track overall with pointing me to virtualisation, but you definitely helped me.  I knew it must be that god awful loop, but as I didn't write it, I had hope I wouldn't need to refactor it by clever use of threads.  My bad.  GridView (https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) has been my saviour!

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as it go me going, and this, along with Slaw pointing out ListViews made me take a step back and use my brain like I would if I developed it from the ground up!  Thank you very much!